# Unable to import scipy module

Tags: python, module, importerror, replit

I am attempting to import the scipy module into my code in order to use the KDTree function. This is done on replit.

I wrote "from scipy import spatial", and on running it errors saying "no module named 'scipy'".

I have tried importing various things from scipy, but it says that scipy doesn't exist.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to install it using command `pip install scipy`

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` is not a built-in but it is an external python package.
For this reason you have to install it before to use it.

You can use the following command in your terminal:

```bash
pip install scipy
```

There also other way to install it, check [the documentation](https://scipy.org/install/) for more details.

My suggestion (but it is not mandatory) is to use a virtualenv.
[Here](https://devinsimplewords.com/python-virtual-environment/) you can find a tutorial on how to create it and how to use it.